# Mongo DB: Failed to connect on Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, mongodb, homestead

I need to create a new Laravel project and I need to use Mongo DB as a database server. Following the Homestead documentation I added this in my **Homeasted.yaml** file:

```
mongodb: true
```

From what I see in the logs the mongo database is created:

```
homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Mongo Database: homestead
```

But after this I received this message:

```
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Mongo Database: homestead
    homestead-7: MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
    homestead-7: connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/homestead
    homestead-7: 2019-06-03T10:01:52.103+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
    homestead-7: 2019-06-03T10:01:52.104+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
    homestead-7: connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
    homestead-7: @(connect):1:6
    homestead-7: exception: connect failed
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
```

From what I found on the internet it can be that the mongo service is not started. I restarted the box without provisioning this time but with the same result. Command:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ mongo
```

Also, I found some solutions that involve changing of some files on an Ubutu O.S but in my case it will not work because the box will start as a fresh instance.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Laravel version: 5.8.
Homestead: 8.4.0
MongoDB shell: v3.6.3

**LATER EDIT**

After the VM has started I executed this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

After installation I can execute the "**mongo**" command:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
        http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
        http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-use
```

Strange, so actually Mongo DB isn't installed?! Even if I added the flag. Now I need to figure how to add it every time when the VM is started.

Comment: SSH into your enviroment with `vagrant ssh` and run `netstat -tulpn` is mongodb listet in this output?

Comment: @Markus, no....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem after hours of searching so I will post the fix.
Because I didn't find anything that could help me I started to check the Homestead scripts in order to understand how Mongo is installed and in **homestead.rb** I found this line:

```
# Install MongoDB If Necessary
if settings.has_key?('mongodb') && settings['mongodb']
  config.vm.provision 'shell' do |s|
    s.name = 'Installing MongoDb'
    s.path = script_dir + '/install-mongo.sh'
  end
end
```

So I searched were "**install-mongo.sh**" is called and I found this condition:

```
if [ -f /home/vagrant/.mongo ]
then
    echo "MongoDB already installed."
    exit 0
fi
```

So Mongo DB is not installed every time only if the "/home/vagrant/.mongo" file doesn't exist. At this point I realized that maybe Mongo failed to be installed but this file was written.

So the solution was to destroy the Vagrant box and recreate it from scratch:

```
vagrant destroy
vagrant up --provision
```

Answer (score 0):

In Homestead.yaml under features: add `-mongodb: true`

and run `vagrant reload --provision`, that is same as what @NicuVlad has suggested but little bit easier.